# PHP : execute python file contains Selenium

Tags: php, python, selenium

I have a PHP file where i have a script execute python contains Selenium webdriver but it gives me error in permission :
Php :

```
<?php
echo shell_exec("python test.py 2>&1");
?>
```

test.py :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.send_keys("selenium")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "Google" in driver.title
```

Any suggestion ??

Answer (score 0):

Change file premisions? chmod a+r test.py? What error php give you exacly?

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: "The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. The output was: mkdir: cannot create directory `/.mozilla': Permission denied\nError: no display specified\n"

Comment: ` mkdir: cannot create directory `/.mozilla': Permission denied ` nothing tells you?